# ${d^2y}\over {dt^2}$ rather than ${dy}\over {dt}$ - what does it change$?$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the problem "Find a positive value of $k$ for which $y = \sin(kt)$ satisfies $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + 9y = 0.$

Any example I can find for solving this equation either just uses $y'$ or has a typical $\frac{dy}{dt}$

So what exactly would be changed by doing this$?$

Comment: Um... you take the second derivative.  y = sin(kt).  y' = -k cos kt.  y'' = -k^2 sin kt.  y'' + 9y = 0 so -k^2 sin kt + 9 sin kt = 0 so (-k^2 + 9)sin kt = 0.  Either sin kt is a constant 0 or -k^2 + 9 = 0.  sin kt being a constant 0 means k = 0.  -k^2 + 9 = 0 means k = -/+ 3.  As we want k positive k = 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not being asked to solve this differential equation from scratch.

You've been told that a solution looks like $y=\sin kt$ for some number $k$.

Your task is to find $k$.

Find $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}$ and then find $\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dt^2}$. Substitute $y=\sin kt$ and your expression for $\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dt^2}$ into the equation $\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dt^2} + 9y = 0$, and see if you can tell what $k$ needs to be for the equation to work **for all $t$**.

You'll get two possible solutions for $k$, but you're told that $k>0$, so you can ignore one of them.

[Follow this link](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IntroSecondOrder.aspx) to know how to solve differential equations of the form
$$a\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2} + b\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} + cy = f(x)$$

Comment: Nitpick.  There's a third possible solution of k.  It's not > 0 so you can ignore it as well.

Comment: @fleablood Touché! The trivial solution ($k=0$) would also work. I never consider constant solutions to ODEs, but I should. Degenerate solutions can be very interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Like I said.  It was a nitpick.

Answer (score 1):

Notice:

- $$\frac{\text{d}y(t)}{\text{d}t}=y'(t)$$
- $$\frac{\text{d}^2y(t)}{\text{d}t^2}=y''(t)$$

  ---

So, find the solution to $y''(t)+9y(t)=0$ which will look like $y(t)=\sin(kt)$

You can do two things, fill the given solution in, or find the general solution first:

- Hint for method 1:

$$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\left[\sin(kt)\right]+9\sin(kt)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-k^2\sin(kt)+9\sin(kt)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-(k^2-9)\sin(kt)=0$$

- Hint for method 2, using Laplace Transform:

$$y''(t)+9y(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{t}\left[y''(t)+9y(t)\right]_{(s)}=\mathcal{L}_{t}\left[0\right]_{(s)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{t}\left[y''(t)\right]_{(s)}+9\mathcal{L}_{t}\left[y(t)\right]_{(s)}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{t}\left[y''(t)\right]_{(s)}+9y(s)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$s^2y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+9y(s)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(s^2+9)y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(s)=\frac{y(0)s+y'(0)}{s^2+9}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(s)=\frac{sy(0)}{s^2+9}+\frac{y'(0)}{s^2+9}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[y(s)\right]_{(t)}=\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{sy(0)}{s^2+9}+\frac{y'(0)}{s^2+9}\right]_{(t)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(t)=\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{sy(0)}{s^2+9}\right]_{(t)}+\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{y'(0)}{s^2+9}\right]_{(t)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(t)=y(0)\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{s^2+9}\right]_{(t)}+y'(0)\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s^2+9}\right]_{(t)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(t)=y(0)\cos(3t)+\frac{y'(0)\sin(3t)}{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(t)=\text{C}_1\cos(3t)+\frac{\text{C}_2\sin(3t)}{3}$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: **It wasn't me that down-voted.** But I suspect that the Laplace method was the problem. It wasn't at all necessary, and it wasn't even complete - what are the inverse Laplace transforms? If the OP can't substitute a function into an ODE then s/he might have difficulty with inverse integral transforms.

Comment: @FlybyNight I did now, but I showed two methods and the first one is more straight forward but the second one is not wrong, it's the more complicated way of solving! It's not right that my answer gets downvoted!!

Comment: I agree that your second method was correct, but it wasn't that helpful for the OP. Your first method was useful, but I think it was drowned out by the second. Have an upvote for the first method  :)

Comment: @FlybyNight I saw, but the second method is correct, but not the one that the OP want, that's why I showed two methods

Comment: Don't feel bad. You were trying to help, and that's all that matters.

Comment: @FlybyNight You're right, but I've got an idea of who did downvote me and he did it to my previous answers without any reason that's why I got bad

Comment: I've had points "refunded" in the past. If the software sees that someone keeps downvoting your posts then it cancels the downvotes and returns the points. Besides, don't worry about imaginary internet points. You're here to help people, and that's what matters. Screw the score